# How to sign up the user with the custom user model

Tags: django, django-models

When i am signing up the user in the custom signin form i am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'App.MyUser'

**Views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = userObj['username']
            password = userObj['password']
            fname = userObj['fname']
            lname = userObj['lname']
            print (username,password,fname,lname)
            if(len(password)<8):
                messages.error(request,"This password length should be minimum 8 characters")
                #raise ValidationError("This password length should be minimum 8 characters ")
            validate_password_strength(password)
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
                p = Event(fname=fname, lname=lname, username=username)
                p.set_password(password)
                p.save()
                # return HttpResponseRedirect('Login.html')
                return redirect('/Login/')
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like a username with that username or password already exists')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form':form})
```

**settings.py**:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ("django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
                               'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'App.Event'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url('Appname/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        url(r'^signup/', views.signup,name='signup'),
        url(r'^Login/', views.Login,name='Login'),
        url(r'^Logout/', views.Logout,name='Logout'),
    ]
```

**models.py**

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, fname, lname, username, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given username, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        user = self.model(username=username, fname=fname, lname=lname)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_active = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        print(user)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, fname, lname, username, password, email=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given username and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            fname=fname,
            lname=lname,
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Event(AbstractBaseUser):
    fname = models.CharField('fname', max_length=120)
    lname = models.CharField('lname', max_length=120)
    username = models.CharField('username', max_length=60, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField('password', max_length=120, default='xxxxxx@2789')

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['fname', 'lname']

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username

    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = "user"
```

When i am changing the `App.MyUser` to `auth.User`, the login is not happening eventhough it is returning the username and password But when i am changing the `auth.User` to `App.MyUser` signin is not happening and it is throwing the error.  So how to make both to work with the same `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

Comment: Your custom user model name is Event not User,

Comment: @Bidhan Majhi  i am using the app.Event only.

Comment: You are using this `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'` where you don't have any User model

Comment: @BidhanMajhi I have edited my question i am using AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'App.Event' Only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've swapped out the user model, but you still do a query explicitly against User in the line:

```
if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()):
```

That should be Event, not User. But note that *you should not be doing this at all*; the UserRegistrationForm already checks for uniqueness. That whole condition should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Since your custom user model is **`Event`**, It should be

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app_name.Event'
```

where the ***`your_app_name`*** is the name of the django app **`Event`** model belongs